# Save to temporary file with curl and move in place only if succeeded

Tags: curl

`curl` is able to download a URL to specific file with the `-o`/`--output` switch. AFAIk this will save this file as it goes, and if something happens to the download, then the file will only be half downloaded.

I can work around this, by creating a temp file, and moving that in place:

```
TEMP=$(mktemp -p /data/path/to/results/ tmp.results.zip.XXXXXX)
curl -o ${TEMP} https://example.com/files/results.zip
mv ${TEMP} /data/path/to/results/results.zip
```

Can I do this all in one command just with curl? Does curl have any option for “Save to temp file & only move over if succeeded?”

*Update:* I often use `set -o errexit`, so if the curl command fails, the script will fail. `mv` run iff `curl` didn't fail.

Comment: You could just replace "mv ${TEMP} /data/path/to/results/results.zip" with if [ $? -eq 0 ] then mv ${TEMP} /data/path/to/results/results.zip fi

Comment: @summertime good catch!  I've updated the question to explain that I use `errexit` to prevent that

Comment: Thanks Rory! Would this work: replace "mv ${TEMP} /data/path/to/results/results.zip" with: if [ -e $TEMP ] then mv ${TEMP} /data/path/to/results/results.zip fi

Comment: @summertime the file will exist even if the download fails. I don’t think there’s anything better than the `errexit` approach.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt, ok good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `curl` doesn’t have this built-in; your approach is as good as it gets (with `errexit`). You can make it explicit, regardless of the settings, with

```
curl -o ${TEMP} https://example.com/files/results.zip &&
mv ${TEMP} /data/path/to/results/results.zip
```